# WooCommerce returning error

Tags: json, wordpress, api, post, woocommerce

While trying to create a dummy order through cURL I am getting this error. I tried to create the order via postmaster. I am simply copying the code from the woocommerrce [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order) but still the error is comming
the code is

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/javascript" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 56032927-8d69-3630-aae9-0eb6823fe9b0" -d '{
      "payment_method": "cod",
      "payment_method_title": "Cash on Delivery",
      "set_paid": true,
      "billing": {
        "first_name": "bhbhub",
        "last_name": "Dnuoe",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "beach",
        "state": "Goa",
        "postcode": "122002",
        "country": "India",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "phone": "1234567890"
      },
      "shipping": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "beach",
        "state": "Goa",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US"
      },
      "line_items": [
        {
          "product_id": 100,
          "quantity": 2
        }

      ],
      "shipping_lines": [
        {
          "method_id": "flat_rate",
          "method_title": "Flat Rate"


        }
      ]
    }' "http://www.jersershor.com/wc-api/v3/orders?oauth_consumer_key=ck_638caaf46271a320075ecee01e89581f91644b98&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1484290102&oauth_nonce=cwidKMBu2uE&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=VUMuuVRXsXKvyFhk97dQWj5bCEI%3D
"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the documentation of woocommerce

need to wrap your request body JSON in an `order` object to start. so it'd be like { "order": { ...the data above } }

so the code of the body will be

{
    "order": {

```
"status": "processing",

    "payment_details": {
        "method_id": "bacs",
        "method_title": "Direct Bank Transfer",
        "paid": true

    },

    "billing_address": {
        "first_name": "bhbhub",
        "last_name": "Dnuoe",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "beach",
        "state": "Goa",
        "postcode": "122002",
        "country": "IN",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "phone": "1234567890"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "beach",
        "state": "Goa",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "IN"
    },
    "line_items": [{
            "product_id": 100,
            "quantity": 2
        }

    ],
    "customer": {
        "id": 0,
        "total_spent": "320",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "first_name": "bhbhub",
        "last_name": "Dnuoe",
        "billing_address": {
            "first_name": "bhbhub",
            "last_name": "Dnuoe",
            "company": "",
            "address_1": "969 Market",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "beach",
            "state": "Goa",
            "postcode": "122002",
            "country": "IN",
            "email": "john.doe@example.com",
            "phone": "1234567890"
        },
        "shipping_address": {
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "company": "",
            "address_1": "969 Market",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "beach",
            "state": "Goa",
            "postcode": "94103",
            "country": "IN"
        }
    }
}
```

}